IIS Rewrite module unexpectedly returns different values
The website where this occurs is set up as follows.
wwwroot
    |
    +--testproject
         |--web.config
         +--public
         |    |
         |    |--index.php
         |    +--assets
         |          |
         |          +--js
         |              |
         |              |--testscript.js
         +--app…

The contents of web.config file are
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite routed access to assets javascript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)(\/js\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*.js)$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="public/assets{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Rewrite requested file/folder to index.php" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>

The contents of index.php are
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Testpage</h1>
        <h3>Text from javascript testscript.js</h3>
        <div id="testdiv"></div>
        <script src="js/testscript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

The contents of testscript.js are
var e = document.getElementById("testdiv")
e.innerHTML = "Lorum ipsum...";

Question: why does "http://localhost/testproject/users" give an error message when loading the JavaScript, but at "http://localhost/testproject/users/23" the script is started correctly?
System info: Windows 11; IIS 10.0; IIS Rewrite Module 2.

You can help yourself to get started with FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules
